# Python Flask Blueprints - ImportError: cannot import name app

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, flask, python-import

I am working through a tutorial on flask blueprints, and the first step is to just to download flask and get initial "Hello World" printed. However when I try to run the initial run.py file I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from site import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'site' (/Users/kyle/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site.py)
```

My file structure is:

```
website/
     run.py
     site/
        __init__.py
```

**run.py**

```
from site import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def root():
    return "Hello World"
```

I am confused why I am getting this error since from what I understand if app is declared in the **init** file I should be able to import it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because *site* is a module within the Python standard library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html). Your module name is clashing with it and the interpreter is loading from the library first, hence not finding the *app* variable. There are a few ways around this but I suspect you're not very attached to the name so I'd just change it. If you rename your **site** folder to **web** (or any other name not used by the Python std library), it'll work.